# Difference between "in the interest of" and "in order to"

Tags: meaning, difference

> Exercise shouldn’t be drudgery, although too often it is when we’re
>   slogging on the treadmill or doing mindless laps in the pool. **In the
>   interest of** combining exercise with an element of fun, the Los
>   Angeles Athletic Club in downtown L.A. kicks off its “Move to a Movie”
>   monthlong workout series that combines films with complementary themed
>   workouts.
>
> https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-2010-aug-30-la-heb-workout-20100830-story.html

What is the difference between "in the interest of" and "in order to"? They seem similar in their definitions. Why does the writer use "in the interest of" here?

> in the interest of (something):
>
> **In order to** accomplish, improve, or advance something.
>
> https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+interest+of
>
> in order to:
>
> For the purpose of
>
> https://www.thefreedictionary.com/in+order+to

Comment: Using the definitions provided, “in the interest of” means “for the purpose of accomplishing, improving, or advancing something. Can you explain a bit more about why that doesn’t help?

Comment: I was thinking about the semantic difference between these two expressions. I have got a very  good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a grammatical difference. "In order to" expects an infinitive verb phrase, while "in the interest of" takes a noun phrase, often formed with a [gerund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund).

> In order **to lose weight**, I will exercise every day. (verb phrase)
>
> In the interest of **losing weight**, I will exercise every day. (noun phrase formed with gerund)

Here is another example, where a gerund is not an option and the grammatical difference is clearer:

> In the interest of **safety**, please wear a hard hat.
>
> In order to **be safe**, please wear a hard hat.

---

In terms of meaning, the two are almost interchangeable. The difference is subtle: "in order to" is more direct than "in the interest of."

"In order to X, Y" suggests that action Y is meant to directly accomplish goal X, perhaps in conjunction with other actions. There is a direct intent for Y to achieve X, in whole or in part.

"In the interest of X, Y" is less direct: it only means that action Y was chosen or planned with X in mind. It may not directly achieve or accomplish X, but it may be better for X than some other alternative action Z.